# nowjs not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nowjs-sockets

I successfully installed nowjs on my server. Now I'm trying this tutorial: http://nowjs.com/doc/example
I created both files and put them into var/www/test
By running this command

```
node helloworld_server.js
```

in putty I get an error:

```
module.js:337
    throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + request + "'");
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'now'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
    at require (module.js:375:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/helloworld_server.js:7:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
```

The installation worked fine and node is correctly installed. I'm a beginner in administrating a server, but whats wrong with the code?
Thanks!

Comment: You ask what is wrong with the code but you aren't showing any code.

Comment: see the nowjs example. I don't think the example is wrong, but something must be wrong with my installation ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very generic error that tells you Node.js can't find the module. If you did npm install module in the root of your project you should have a node_module directory. Inside that directory you should be able to see the modules you installed.

Comment: Where should the root of the project be located?

Comment: I have the same problem. There is a folder called "usr/local/lib/node_modules/now" with some files in it, but I keep getting the same error message.